# jQuery/CSS semicircle progress bar with different colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am new to jQuery and CSS3. I need the following HTML to look like this:

[image: here]

Please help me.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>10</span>%
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>100</span>%
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>34</span>%
</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="barOverflow">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>67</span>%
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is,

I didn't actually get your question, but here is what I came up with, you can make changes accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
  background: transparent;
  width: 120px; height: 120px;
  border: 12px solid;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-right-color: red;
  border-bottom-color: green;
  border-left-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) }
  100% { transform: rotate(359deg) }
}
```

Do add the vendor prefixes for properties such as animation, transform, etc.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response..

I need like https://jsfiddle.net/sqwdkrg0/1782/ .. with different color and text like on stages 25% 50% 75%.. Hope you understand..